# How do I include large quantities of code to my html?

Tags: html

How do I include large quantities of code (300 lines) to my html? I've tried scrollbars, but that has no syntax highlighting and somehow deletes all of the line breaks in my original code. The code is on gitlab, so I tried its "snippets" feature (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html), but it is poorly documented and I cannot get it work. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for JavaScript libraries, such as Google's [Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag) or search for "JavasSript syntax highlighter".