# Export syntax highlighting as html

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode does a nice job at syntax highlighting.  I'd like to include some of that nice colored text in a webpage.  Is there a way to export/render/save as an html file with html tags/css syntax highlighting?

Example Input:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello")
```

Desired Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>/.../hello.py.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Vim/7.1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000"><font face="monospace">
<font color="#a52a2a"><b>if</b></font>&nbsp;__name__ == '<font color="#ff00ff">__main__</font>':<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#a52a2a"><b>print</b></font>(&quot;<font color="#ff00ff">Hello</font>&quot;)<br>
<br>
</font></body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, there are a lot of good syntax highlighters you can use on a webpage, on the fly cloloring

Comment: check out this question, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag

Comment: Thank you.  After experimenting a bit, I agree.  Using a javascript browser highlighter is better than what I was trying to do.