# How to get the text of the js method based on the method name to display in html

Tags: javascript

For example when I press the button it execute

```
 function test(){console.log('test')};
```

At this time

Is there any tools or component which can show this complete method text in html, so I can use some code like showCode('test') to show it

Comment: like `console.log(test)`?

Comment: no,  i just want to show the whole function text in html ,like the code box above

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for a way to print code on an html page and highlight it properly? If that's the case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag