# Change Word Colors Textarea to SQL Syntax

Tags: html, reactjs, textarea

I am currently developing an application that requires the utilization of a text input featuring SQL code. Within this application, it is imperative that the input interface dynamically adjusts the color scheme in alignment with the SQL code, thereby enhancing user interaction and syntax comprehension.

My development framework of choice is React, yet I've encountered a hurdle in locating a suitable solution that affords me the flexibility to tailor the color scheme according to my preferences. To illustrate my desired outcome, refer to the visual representation below:

[image]

Presently, I am employing the textarea tag as the input mechanism, albeit lacking any supplementary visual enhancements. I am inquiring whether there exists a viable avenue to customize the color palette for the input text. Alternatively, I am open to discovering tools that empower me to seamlessly harmonize the color scheme with the SQL code syntax.

For reference, here is the current state of my design:

[image]

I expect different ways to customize the textarea tag to add a design to the SQL syntax so I can customize the colors as the user writes in the input box.
[image]

Comment: I found a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag) about syntax highlighting which I hope will help.